Sending an image through WhatsApp using Python
I am trying to send an .jpg image using PyWhatKit package in python.  I can send text. But when I try to send an image, it gives me an error:
(WhatsApp) manunat@Manus-iMac-2 test % python3 send_msg1.py
2024-05-18 08:31:58.137 osascript[1576:27338] CFURLGetFSRef was passed a URL which has no scheme (the URL will not work with other CFURL routines)
The code is as per the package's document.
import pywhatkit as pwk

phone_num = "+919xxxxxxxxx"
pwk.sendwhats_image(phone_num, "image.jpg")

The version of Python is 3.12.3 on macOS 14.2.1 (Sonoma).
Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Where is "image.jpg" located on your OS?

Replace "image.jpg" with absolute path.

I saved it in the same directory as the python script.

I used the absolute path.  The program executed without any error.  But, no image was sent.  Apparently, the image got copied to the clipboard. But, was not sent as an attachement in the WhatsApp message, but some previously entered text in the message was always displayed.

Can I use JavaScript instead to achieve this ?  Thanks in advance.

Steps to Install and Start the CopyQ Server

Install CopyQ:
Use the following command to install CopyQ on your system:
sudo apt install copyq


Start the CopyQ Server:
Launch the CopyQ server in the background by running:
copyq &

The & ensures the server runs in the background, so you can continue using the terminal.

Run Your Script:
After starting the CopyQ server, execute your script, and it should work without any issues.


